# Is posenet a machine learning model or deep learning model

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I want to know if posenet in tensorflow.js can be called as a machine learning model or deep learning model. I have searched the internet and found that some websites say it as a machine learning model while some say it is a deep learning model.

Also provide reasons for the saying if it is a machine learning based or deep learning based.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Deep learning is just a subset of machine learning and PoseNet is both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep Learning is a [subset](https://www.zendesk.com/blog/machine-learning-and-deep-learning/) of Machine Learning. Posenet is a DL model, specifically in Computer Vision. Technically, since all DL models are ML models, it can be called an ML model. However, if to be stated specifically, it is a DL model.